# Using HashMaps to find string frequencies

Tags: java, string, hashmap, substring

My code is meant to find the most frequent codon from a file that contains a lonf string of DNA (i.e. CTAAATCGATGGCGATGATAAATG...). starting at the initial position `pos`, every three characters makes up one codon. The problem I have is that whenever I run the code, it tell me that the string index is out of range. I know that the issue is in the line

```
str = line.substring(idx, idx + 2);
```

but don't know how to fix it. Also, I am not sure whether I am counting frequencies correctly. I needed to increment the value of every key that is seen more than once.

```
public static void findgene(String line){
            int idx, pos;
            int[] freq = new int[100];
            String str;

            //pos is the position to start at
            pos = 0;
            idx = pos;

            for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
                if(idx >= 0){
                    //makes every three characters into a codon
                    str = line.substring(idx, idx + 2);
                    //checks if the codon was previously seen
                    if(genes.containsKey(str)){
                        genes.put(str, freq[i]++);
                    }
                    idx = idx + 2;
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `idx` by 2 with each iteration of the loop. However, you did not impose any restriction on the upper limit of `idx`.

Thus the the parameter of the `substring()` function soon goes out of range in the line:

```
str = line.substring(idx, idx + 2);
```

What you need to do is change the condition to:

```
if(idx+2<=line.length()){
    //code here
}
```